# How do I split comma separrated text file not for one line, but for a several line files?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am completely new to nifi and I am learning SplitText processor.

So here's the case. I have the comma separated txt file, something like this:

```
KeyWord, SomeInformation   <---1st line is schema.

KeyWord1, "information"

KeyWord2, "information"

KeyWord1, "another information"

KeyWord2, "another information"

 

and so on.
```

So the question is how can I split this file on a few files based on KeyWord? So the every line with KeyWord1 go to one file, every line with KeyWord2 go to another file and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PartitionRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.16.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PartitionRecord/index.html) and add a user-defined property called `keyword` (the name is arbitrary but will be the name of the attribute added to each outgoing FlowFile) with value `/KeyWord`. It will create FlowFiles where one contains all rows whose `Keyword` field is `KeyWord1`, another for `KeyWord2`, and so on.